# Copying data from local .CSV file to pgsql table in remote server

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy data from a csv file from my local machine into a remote pgsql table named states, but i am getting an ERROR: Syntax error at or near "FROM". Can someone guide me as to why i am receiving this error?

```
   COPY FROM STDIN states FROM '/Users/Shared/data.csv'  DELIMITER AS ',';
```

Comment: replace FROM STDIN with TO and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: oops. remove TO. It shoiuld be COPY states FROM '....' DELIMITER AS ',';

Comment: Your suggestion works perfect if i am copying the csv to a table on my local machine. My issue is copying the csv into a table on a pgsql server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the path to the file is in the remote server, not the local one.

you need psql and pipe the file to STDIN:

```
psql -h host -d remoteDB -U myuser -c  "copy states from STDIN with delimiter as ',';" < /path/file.csv
```

alternatively you can also do:

```
cat /path/file.csv | psql -h host -d remoteDB -U myuser -c  "copy states from STDIN with delimiter as ',';"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer dmg. But...... The path to the file is on my local machine. The table "states" is on the pgsql server. I'm not sure if  that was clear

Comment: sorry Michael, i forgot to add < before the path name. It should work now (I tried myself)

Comment: ahhh shucks man, i now get *-bash: /Users/Shared/data.csv: No such file or directory*. My csv file is in the shared folder. I tripled checked it.

Comment: are you sure? Do, in terminal also: ls /Users/Shared/data.csv and see if it is there. It sounds like: either, it cannot read it, or it is not there.

Comment: My only suggestion is to check that the capitalization of the name is the same. You can alternatively use:  cat /Users/Shared/data.csv | psql -h host -d remoteDB -U myuser -c  "copy states from STDIN with delimiter as ',';"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly with a filename unless the file is on the Postgres server. [The docs of COPY state](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html):

> COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read from or write to a file. The file must be accessible to the server and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server. When STDIN or STDOUT is specified, data is transmitted via the connection between the client and the server.

You'll have to pipe the file in via STDIN.

Many Postgres drivers provide a method to make this easier. For example, [ruby-pg provides `copy_data`](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-copy_data).

```
conn.copy_data "COPY states FROM STDIN FORMAT CSV" do
  File.foreach('/Users/Shared/data.csv') do |line|
    conn.put_copy_data(line)
  end
end
```

Comment: The file should be accessible by the postgres client, file need not be present only on server.

Comment: @raj240 Perhaps you're thinking of `\copy` in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html)?